# QT, Populating combobox from array

Tags: c++, arrays, qt, combobox

I need help in populating a combobox from an array which holds the data that came from a text file, ive already check that the array String had really got the data, the problem is that i cannot populate the combo box from the array.

```
std::string String[10];
std::string str,tmp;
std::ifstream ifs;
int y=0;
ifs.open("file.txt);
        while (!ifs.eof())
        {
            getline(ifs, str, '\n');
            String[y]=str;
            y++;
        }
        ifs.close();

ui->Destination->addItems(String);
```

This is what ive got so far....

Comment: Why do you need an array? You can add strings you read from file directly into the combo box in the `while` loop.

Comment: can you somehow given an example on that?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/why-is-iostreameof-inside-a-loop-condition-considered-wrong

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the array, ive already check that using Visual Studio, I just dont know how to populate the combo box with the data inside the array.

Comment: `QComboBox::addItems` takes a `QStringList` as an argument, so why don't you just use a `QStringList`? Or do as vahancho said and use `QComboBox::addItem` in your `while` loop.

Comment: That is why im asking a sample on that. But the data came from a text file and i put it into array because i thought i can just do the c++ style of passing things around, but i was wrong.

Comment: @PatrickJohn, what if you instead of `String[y]=str;` in your example simply write `ui->Destination->addItem(str.c_str());`? Assuming that `ui->Destination` is a combo box.

Comment: The problem has already been resolved.